# DB update randomly throwing Validation Error MVC 4 EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have a controller which updates just 2 fields in a db entry, however that entry is linked to two other tables, I know it's a bad explanation but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I cant identify what's different between submissions since no code changes.

**Error** 
[image]

**Controller**

```
GroupFitnessSession session = unitOfWork.GroupFitnessSessionRepository.GetById(item.GroupFitnessSessionId);
session.IsConfirmed = true;
session.Attendees = item.Attendees;
unitOfWork.GroupFitnessSessionRepository.Update(session);
```

There are other fields to the Models that i've left out, but non of them are the same name or something to these oens

**Models**

```
public class GroupFitnessSession
{
    public string GroupFitnessSessionId { get; set; }
    [Required] 
    public virtual Trainer Trainer { get; set; }
    [Required] 
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}


public class Location
{
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location()
    {
        GroupFitnessSession = new HashSet<GroupFitnessSession>();
    }
    public ICollection<GroupFitnessSession> GroupFitnessSession { get; set; }
}
public class Trainer
{
    public Trainer()
    {
        GroupFitness = new HashSet<GroupFitnessSession>();        
    }
    public ICollection<GroupFitnessSession> GroupFitness { get; set; }
```

If you need any other information feel free to ask.
This is just confusing me too much, any advice would be appceiated

EDIT: showing that Location and Trainer are not empty objects
[image]

As you can see the auto generated Properties from EF aswell as the propertiy I am trying to update

[image]

Comment: why are you placing required attribute for the class object???

Comment: @COLDTOLD So that EF can determine the principle end when creating the DB via code first

Comment: I am not sure how required is doing what you want but,  I am sure that the errors you are getting are validation errors is because Trainer or Location have no data

Comment: @COLDTOLD  I am reasonably certain that it is doing what I expect , since without it EF would not know what the principle end of the relationship is and not build the db. And no, the objects Location and Trainer are not empty (I have checked and can show a SS if you don't believe me), even if they were an empty object would still pass the required vaildation

Comment: Not based on the error screenshot you are sharing you even highlighted that error "The Trainer field is required" means your entity is failing validation.

Comment: Does your model contain the associated navigation properties for the FK ( e.g. `[Required] public int TrainerID { get; set; }`)? And you should not need the `[Required]` attribute on the virtual properties

Comment: @StephenMuecke My model does not explicitly contain those properties since from my understanding EF creates those properties and on my DB I can see them, I can also show this in a SS with the test data if needed.

Comment: @COLDTOLD I have uploaded a SS to show you the above.

Comment: It still has same errors.

Comment: @COLDTOLD I don't understand how you are trying to help, I know it has the same error, it's always the same error, yet there is nothing wrong with it since the entry is already in the DB, I am only updating 2 properties, one int and one bool none of which are related to anything else

Comment: Stephen Muecke, already explained to you the solution you are making entire entity required which why you are getting the error, you said it suppose to be that way, I am not sure how, but when it works that property is set when it does not the property is empty and required.

Comment: @COLDTOLD YES, It is now working, thank you. You were right, I didn't understand how Required worked on a Virtual property, I thought it just had to be there but didn't know that it made all fields in that model required aswell

Comment: Relations between entities should be defined in fluent api, not using attributes (exception being `ForeignKey` attribute, but still it's better to define that in fluent api imo)

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you change the first line of the controller to:

```
GroupFitnessSession session = unitOfWork.GroupFitnessSessionRepository.GetById(item.GroupFitnessSessionId).Include(s => s.Trainer).Include(s => s.Location);
```